# Disable ipython show output in minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, ipython, elpy

I am using Ipython 3.6.3 with Emacs(elpy enabled) 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 17.10.

I realize that sometimes output of Ipython keep showing at minibuffer, which is very annoying.

But, I cannot find the value for customizing this feature. So, could you please give me a hint on this issue?

Comment: Please try to provide more information - preferably a recipe to reproduce the problem. "Sometimes..." is not much to go on. Otherwise, the question risks being closed as unclear. Thx.

Comment: I have had similar experiences and can't reproduce it using `emacs -q`. I assume it's something in my init.  However, a fresh load of Emacs and a fresh load of my init doesn't reproduce the problem.  Does the problem happen consistently for you?  If so, I would like to see your `init.el`.

Comment: `(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython3.5"
python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt")`
`--simple-prompt` seems solve this problem

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't fix it for me...